# How can we pass List through named route in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, routes, flutter-navigation, named-routing

I just wanted to know how I can pass the whole list as an argument through Navigator.pushnamed() in Flutter. Is it possible or not? If I m trying to pass list n its showing The argument type 'List' cannot be assigned to 'String'

Answer (score 0):

The list that you want to pass;

```
List yourList = [];
```

pass it through the Navigator;

```
Navigator.pushNamed(
  context,
  'routeName',
  arguments: yourList,
);
```

and get your list in target widget;

```
List _yourListFromArguments;

@override
void didChangeDependencies() {
  _yourListFromArguments = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
  super.didChangeDependencies();
}
```